# Flask: serve template in another folder (other than 'templates/' directory)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have generated sphinx documentation for my project into documentation folder. Now I want to serve that using a flask server.

This is my project structure. I want to serve `example.html` from the documentation folder. That folder also has relevant CSS files required for it.

```
app/
    module1/
    module2/
    documentation/
        build/
            example.html
            styles.css
            ...
    templates/
        other_files.html
        ...
```

### app_controller.py

```
@application.route("/doc", methods=["GET"])
@log_exceptions_to_github
def doc():
    return render_template('/build/index.html')
```

#### Issue:

Flask looks for HTML files in the "templates" folder only by default.

So I am not able to serve this. Note that copying from documentation dir to templates dir is not what I want to do because of project requirements.

**I want to add "documentation" folder as a templates directory along with the default one.**

I have tried this but it is not working:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598839/2286762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Flask docs about [how to organize templates](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/templates.html#how-to-organize-templates) in Flask.

So why not simply put your `documentation` directory under the `templates` directory like this:

```
templates/
    index.html
    documentation/
        build/
            example.html
    other_directories/
```

And then simply call `return render_template('documentation/build/example.html')`

If you really want to keep your structure like you proposed in your code example, you can have a look at the question about [How to load from more then one template_folder for Flask blueprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11193848/2808371).

In Flask documentation you can find out more about [what is a blueprint](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html#what-is-a-blueprint).

Comment: Already tried it. Documentation folder has related css files too. Those Css paths are breaking if i do this.

Comment: @KishanMehta any stack trace? Also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519004/2808371) in addition to the methods described in the answer above to serve static files from other locations than `static` directory

Comment: Ok the process is, I am using sphinx documentation generation command `make html` the html is generated automatically based on .rst files. Issue is I can't use "custom_static" tag in the auto generated html by sphinx. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @KishanMehta so it's a problem with sphinx if I understood correctly. That sounds like a topic for a new question then.

Comment: Okay. I thought there might be a way to add multiple templates & static folders like we can do in django. Anyways, I will take another approach.